# Visual Studio Code - Java - Lombok - The method is undefined for the type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code, lombok, java-annotations

I downloaded the following project and imported it into `Visual Studio Code`:

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-5-example

I have a problem on the following class, when invoking: `car.getName()`.

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-5-example/blob/d5c959162ed0f862a5dceb93f5957f92e052e062/server/src/main/java/com/okta/developer/demo/CoolCarController.java

which content is:

**CoolCarController.java**

```
package com.okta.developer.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
class CoolCarController {
    private CarRepository repository;

    public CoolCarController(CarRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/cool-cars")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public Collection<Car> coolCars() {
        return repository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(this::isCool)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean isCool(Car car) {
        return !car.getName().equals("AMC Gremlin") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Triumph Stag") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Ford Pinto") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Yugo GV");
    }
}
```

here is also the content of:

**Car.java**

```
package com.okta.developer.demo;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
public class Car {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private @NonNull String name;
}
```

As you can see on the image below, I'm getting the error:

```
[Java] The method getName() is undefined for the type Car
```

[image]

I think `Visual Studio Code` doesn't understand the package: `lombok`.

Any idea on how can I make `Visual Studio Code` understand that package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

Ok, Installing extension: `Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code` (gabrielbb.vscode-lombok) did the trick.

Comment: It haven't worked for me. I installed the extension and it sorted out the editor's Intellisense but not the compilation itself. I've got the _"Build Failed, do you want to continue?"_ error message when trying to run the code from within VSCode. If I choose _"Proceed"_, end up with the Error **Unresolved compilation problem**. Multiple Constructors and Methods are undefined.

Comment: I had the same issue as @dbaltor. I updated the VS Code to the latest and the lombok issues are gone. It's compiling fine without any issues.

Comment: As @Suresh said, I updated to the last version of VS Code and then clearing the Workspace cache (by clicking on the Fix button when trying to running the app) did the trick. I also had installed the extension Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code.

Answer (score 48):

If your project loads before installing this plugin `Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code`, you can run this command in vscode to reload the project.

Press `Command + shift + P` and execute:

```
Java: Clean Java language server workspace
```

Comment: This should be stated in the VSCode extension's install instruction.

Comment: This post saved me today..

Comment: Thank you, I was 1 keystroke away from 360 spin high kick my computer..